# Run query with parameters and display in ListBox MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've created a query in Access 2013 that takes two parameters

```
PARAMETERS blah TYPE, blah TYPE;
SELECT * FROM blah WHERE blah blah;
```

I want to run that query and display the result in a listbox.

Normally I would do like

Me.MyListBox.RowSource = "myQuery"

But when I do so, a box is popping up telling me to enter the first parameter. How can I specify the parameters programatically?

My second approach was something like

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myQuery")
    .Parameters("param1") = 1
    .Parameters("param2") = 2
    Me.MyListBox.RowSource = .OpenRecordset()
End With
```

That gave me type mismatch?

How can I do this?

EDIT: To make things clear, I know that I can concatenate strings to build the query I want, something like:

Me.MyListBox.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE abc Like '" & somevalue & "'"

But this is precisely what I want to avoid because it makes the code difficult to maintain and read.

Comment: I think you may need to either rework the query and/or add some vba code. One option is to modify the query so the parameters are replaced by Functions (then you need to specify where the values are); or just add VBA code to create a 'run-time' view of the SQL (i.e. parameter values embedded) and set the rowsource. Someone else may have a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In MySQL you can create a stored procedure that takes a couple of parameters, and you can then run the query using the CALL statement. I though it might be possible to achieve something similar in Access, but I haven't stumbled upon anything yet...

Comment: Yes, the issue is your rowsource is bound to a saved query that prompts for parameters. Is each user supposed to type in the values for the parameters, or are the values available somewhere as a control on a form or in a table? If so, you can change the query to grab the 'current' values.

Comment: The values are the selections from a ListBox and a ComboBox in a form. How can I instruct the query to grab the values from these components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I think I've found what I was looking for.

```
Private Sub SomeButton_Click()
    With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myQuery")
        .Parameters("firstParameter") = 2
        Set Me.MyListBox.Recordset = .OpenRecordset
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want to run an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE instead, I think you can do the same thing, but instead of using OpenRecordset, call Execute.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on if the filter criteria in your listbox is MultiSelect or a single entry, the following will work. You will need to requery your ListBox after making your selections.

```
Public Function sListBox() As String
    If Not IsNull(Forms![frmListbox]![lstDate]) Then
        sListBox = Forms![frmListbox]![lstDate]
    End If
End Function
```

Your Query can look like (reference ComboBox directly and Function for ListBox:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.ProductNumber, CUSTOMER.LastOrder
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE (((CUSTOMER.ProductNumber)=Forms!frmListbox!cboCustomer) 
And ((CUSTOMER.LastOrder)=sListBox()));
```